# $\int_0^1 \exp(f(x))\,dx \geq \exp(\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

As in the title with a bit more detail, assume $f$ is Riemann Integrable from $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$, prove that  $\int_0^1 \exp(f(x))dx \geq  \exp(\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$, I did a bit of research and noticed that this is an example of Jensen's inequality. But how would you prove this without measure theory/purely from the Riemann Integral perspective?

Comment: Please fix your incorrect title.

Comment: Jensen’s inequality will often be proven in a measure/probability theory course but it doesn’t really rely on any measure theory. The fact that the limits of integration are a distance one away from eachother is important though.

Comment: Jensen's inequality is not hard to prove with Riemann sums.  It's a generalization of the definition of convexity.  Convexity says that if $a,b \geq 0 $ and $a+b = 1$then $f(ax + by) \leq af(x) + bf(y)$.  Generalize this to: if $a_1, \ldots, a_n \geq 0$ and $\sum_i a_i = 1$ then $f(\sum_i a_i x_i) \leq \sum_i a_i f(x_i)$. In slogan form, $f$(weighted average) $\leq$ weighted average($f$) for any convex $f$. Now take $n \rightarrow \infty$ and turn things into Riemann sums.  And note that $x \mapsto e^x$ is convex.

Comment: Have a look at [this version](https://rtybase.blogspot.com/2011/01/on-inequality.html).

Comment: More directly, since $x\mapsto\exp(x)$ is convex, $\exp(f(x))\ge\exp(h)+\exp(h)(f(x)-h)$; specialize to $h=\int_0^1f(x)dx$ and integrate.

Answer (score 3):

If $\phi$ is convex (as is $\exp$) we have
$\phi(t) \ge \phi(t_0) + \phi'(t_0) (t-t_0)$.

Hence $\phi(f(x)) \ge \phi(t_0) + \phi'(t_0) (f(x)-t_0)$ (cf. subdifferential).

Now integrate to get
$\int_0^1 \phi(f(x)) dx \ge \phi(t_0) + \phi'(t_0)(\int_0^1 f(x)dx - t_0)$.

Now choose $t_0 = \int_0^1 f(x)dx$ to get $\int_0^1 \phi(f(x)) dx \ge \phi(\int_0^1 f(x)dx)$.